# Java Maven project minify the build

Tags: java, maven, uberjar

I am working on a multi module Maven project. We have created a project which builds an uber jar. The unpacked jar is about 60mb which is a problem for our client.
Are there any tools we can use to remove unused .class files within the dependencies when the build is completed?

Another option would be if we could analyse what .class files are loaded when running and produce a list of these and thus remove others from the build manually.

cheers,

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it could remove classes as such, but [proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/#results.html) has some awesome results in terms of minifying class sizes.  You can see from the link it reduces the Ant module by 90%

Comment: Thanks, I had a go with this and it did shrink the jar. The issue is it removed all of the concrete implementations as the application is heavily di driven by spring. Any ideas? cheers.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd, I wouldn't have thought it'd actually classes, just obfusticate as @AndrewThompson mentioned.  I'm not really a pro-guard expert so you might be better asking another question specifically about proguard.